# Format date output minutes as the fraction of an hour

Tags: date

How do you format the date time output so that 11:30 is printed as 11.5?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: you want every possible value of *minutes* to be truncated to one decimal point? Rounded?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach.

```
$ date
Fri Mar  1 19:30:36 STD 2019
$ date '+%H %M' | awk '{ printf "%d.%d\n",$1,$2/60*10 }'
19.5
$
```

Shorter version

```
$ date '+%H %M'|awk '{$0=$1"."int($2/6)}1'
19.5
$
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, using the 12-hour clock,
but not including the requisite “AM” / “PM” indicator, is

```
date +'scale=1; %I + %M/60' | bc
```

Of course you can capture the output in a variable:

```
dec_time=$(date +'scale=1; %I + %M/60' | bc)
```

This simply executes the calculator (`bc`) with an expression
that is hours (`%I`) plus a fraction of the hour (minutes divided by 60). 
`scale=1` specifies that you want one decimal digit. 
For the 24-hour clock (hour ranges from 0 through 23),
use `%H` instead of `%I`.

This will not give you any padding (leading zero or space)
for hours < 10, and the division truncates down
(11:35 will be reported as “11.5”, not “11.6”).